# Can IP Port use as alphanumeric instead of numeric?

Tags: apache, xampp, ip, port

It is possible if I do like this?
http://myurl:**abc**

Port : **abc** instead of **123**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3), the port part of a URI is defined thus (my bold):

> The port subcomponent of authority is designated by an optional port number ***in decimal*** following the host and delimited from it by a single colon (":") character.

That RFC has been updated by both RFC6874 and RFC7320, but neither of those effect any changes on the relevant section.

Comment: How long can a port be?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, you should ask that as a *question* if you're interested, rather than making a comment. The spec referenced in the answer simply says `*DIGIT` so it allows any number. However, a transport may impose further restriction since, for example, TCP only had 16-bit ports.

Answer (score 2):

No, that cannot be the case. The port is a number always, as [per specification](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).